# I need help with a proof in Hawking & Ellis

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, causality, geodesics

Here's a proof in Hawking and Ellis (1973) of proposition 6.4.6:

[image]

The definition of "strong causality" used in the book is that for every point $p$ and every neighborhood $U$ of $p$, there exists a neighborhood $O$ of $p$ contained in $U$ which no non-spacelike curve intersects more than once.

The conditions (a) to (c) of proposition 6.4.5 are given below:

a) The null energy condition holds on the spacetime $M$, so that $R_{ab}K^aK^b\ge0$ for all null vectors $K^a$.

b) The null generic condition holds, so that every null geodesic contains a point where  $K_{[a}R_{b]cd[e}K_{f]}K^cK^d$ is non-zero ($K^a$ is the tangent vector to the null geodesic).

c) the chronology condition holds on $M$, ie. there are no closed timelike curves in $M$.

In proposition 6.4.5, the authors proved that if conditions (a) to (c) hold, then the causality condition holds on $M$, ie. there are no closed non-spacelike curves in $M$.

I have some questions about the proof of proposition 6.4.6:

1: Why can we assume that for each $V_n$, there exists a non-spacelike curve that passes through $V_n$, leaves $\mathscr U$, and then reenters $V_n$? By the definition of strong causality, can't we only assume that the non-spacelike curve will leave $V_n$ (and not necessarily $\mathscr U$)?

2: I don't quite see why you can "join up some $\lambda_n$ to give a closed non-spacelike curve" if any two points of $\lambda$ have a timelike separation. I would appreciate if anyone could explain more fully how to prove this.